# What MYSQL commands by definition do *not* return a result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm writing a class in PHP for handling MySQLI queries, and when the query manages *not* to return a result set (or object) I want to issue a helpful error message.  But, of course, not all queries are designed to return a result set (e.g. ALTER), so I want to filter out those queries that don't.

By my reckoning, the queries that may or may not return a result set are:

- SELECT
- SHOW
- CREATE VIEW

...and all others (e.g. ALTER) do NOT return a result.  But have I overlooked something?  What are the query commands that never return a result, and what are the query commands that may or may not return a result?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From the PHP manual for [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

I suggest to just check if the return value is equal to false (`=== false`) and do something with [mysqli_errno](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) or [mysqli_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) if it is. Actual parsing of the query string is overkill.

If you must know whether it is a result set or just a boolean, check for the return type with `is_bool($result)` or `$result instanceof mysqli_result`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types basically:

1. Ones that return a result set - it may vary from empty set to a massive amount of data
2. Ones that return a count of affected rows.

There are also three types of queries:

1. DML - queries to manipulate data - select, insert, update, delete.
2. DDL - queries to figure out data schema - create table/view etc.
3. Control queries - grant or revoke permissions

I suppose control queries usually return nothing and DDL queries like create/alter/set also return nothing.
SELECT returns result sets (which may be empty). INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE return the number of rows affected.

I'd recommend reading on SQL queries for more information.